# How do I synchronise Silver Appbar scroll with the list view builder inside it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, appbar

Actually, I'm using a Silver AppBar in Flutter and inside it, I'm using a ListView Builder that has its own scroll. So basically there are two scrolls. But when I scroll List View Builder, Silver AppBar doesn't scroll. I want both of them to scroll from anywhere. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use sliver list istead of list view the problem will solve

here is the link of widget : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can put **NeverScrollableScrollPhysics** as a scroll physics for ListView.builder, so AppBar will scroll as with the content, maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: But then i won't be able to scroll the List view builder. I want it to scroll after Silver appbar